# Here API: Map NAVTECH edge numbers to latitude/longitude?

Tags: here-api

I am using the Here API to search for roads where traffic accidents occur in my home town. My aim is to extract the full road coordinates (as sequence of of lat/lons) where the accident is active in order to draw that road on a reasonable scale.

Using the traffic/6.1/incidents API, I query for the data using a geographical bounding box. An accident in the response is described by  one pair of TMC locations as well as one pair of lat/lon geographical points. This data is too coarse-grained for plotting the roadway. (Please correct me if I am wrong here, but I would like to add some more detail about turns of the road.)

My question regards what I found when I turned to examine the rest of the accident/incident response, containing so-called NAVTECH data on this (XML) form:

<NAVTECH>
<EDGE>
<EDGE_ID>1150578390</EDGE_ID>
<EDGE_ID>1150578391</EDGE_ID>

<EDGE_ID>...</EDGE_ID>

<VERSION_ID>201604</VERSION_ID>
</NAVTECH>

My question is: Is there any available method to map the NAVTECH edges to pairs of lat/lon coordinates?
I have searched Here.com, the here-api stackoverflow tag and tried to Google for an answer, but I find so little documentation on this type of data. I am looking for all information I can find to (i) Describe the NAVTECH edges and their meaning, (ii) How to map NAVTECH to geographical coordinates. In general, (iii) Can I use the Here API to get more geographical information than this about roads where there are accidents?

Kind regards,
Vilhelm from Sweden

Comment: im in the same boat, did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a lat/lon to their routing API and get back the shape point coordinates (and other attributes) for the road edge at that location, like this:

https://route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/getlinkinfo.xml?waypoint=43.066628,-71.471729&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&linkattributes=all

Unfortunately, though, this may not be a long term solution, as seaBass states [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41656152/here-maps-api-get-speed-limit-of-all-roads-in-a-tile):

> `getlinkinfo` will depreciated March 31, 2017. In order to get speed limit information you will have to use PDE (Platform Data Extension) which requires an APP ID and Code