# HERE Maps API - get speed limit of all roads in a tile?

Tags: gps, location, here-api

I'm writing an app that closely tracks a user's driving speed. I'm currently using the HERE API `getlinkinfo` to get the speed limit of a road at a particular point using lat/long.

https://route.st.nlp.nokia.com/routing/7.2/getlinkinfo.json?app_id=APPID&app_code=APPCODE&waypoint=37.421045,-122.092380

When the user is in an intersection or is on/under an overpass the lat/long doesn't specify which road the user is currently on so I don't always get the correct speed limit returned. I believe tiles of data can be read with the Platform Data Extension API but I'm using a plan with only the Standard Feature set so that API is not available. **Is there a way to get all of the speed limits of roads within a certain radius of a point or within a 2 dimensional square using the Standard Feature set?**

Answer (score 1):

`getlinkinfo` will depreciated March 31, 2017.  In order to get speed limit information you will have to use PDE (Platform Data Extension) which requires an APP ID and Code.  If you are working in PHP you can use the link below to help get you started.

[Here PDE Speed Limit Demo](https://github.com/seaBass3/here-pde-speed-limit/blob/master/Here_PDE_Demo.php)

Comment: Do you have a source stating the deprication time frame of getlinkinfo?

Comment: I received a notification from our Here reseller with the following:

HERE has recently informed us that they we will retire the getlinkinfo (beta) functionality of the HLP Router API 7.2 by March 31, 2017. HERE would like to ask you to migrate to the Platform Data Extension by this date to make sure that there will be no service disruption.