# Speed limits with HERE REST API with PDE

Tags: here-api

I've looked into stack overflow for questions similar to mine, namely [HERE Maps API - get speed limit of all roads in a tile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41656152/here-maps-api-get-speed-limit-of-all-roads-in-a-tile)

So this effectively means that https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/routing/link-information-for-a-location will be deprecated, correct?

I also understand that the PDE is the way to go.

However, I couldn't find a simple example on the API Playground (just a simple REST call) that shows how to perform that functionality, e.g. get speed limits for a road.

Is anyone able to provide some clearance? I've read about the key concepts such as tiles and layers but it is quite overwhelming.

Comment: I think you might have better luck over at http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Maybe this example helps a bit ? https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/pde_speed_limits_in_view

Comment: thanks for the help, but that is using the Javascript API, I can't find anything with pure REST. 

I'll have a look at the JS API. cheers

Answer (score 0):

There's an example on GitHub that uses rest to get Speed Limits via Here + PDE. I've tried it and it works well.

https://github.com/seaBass3/here-pde-speed-limit